# Hibernate HSQLDB two sessions

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb

I am learning Hibernate by reading books and doing examples. I am looking at the example on

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Hibernate/UseTwoSessions.htm web site.

This is a well know site that has Java examples. In this example it used HSQLDB which I have running in it's own JVM. For some reason this example seems to hang when the second session is used. So the question is, is there a problem with this example? Can you have a person look at it and determine if it is a valid example.

The problem is in the main classs (see code below)  Event event2 = (Event) session2.load(Event.class, event.getId()); this line hangs

Thanks for our help. NOTE: if this code is bad, please tell the people at www.java2s.com... If it does work, PLEASE tell me what I could be doing wrong..

I am using this example and have increased the connection count and a host of other changes. Is there some change that will make the TwoSessions example work?

Thanks for your help
Richard

public static void main(String[] args) {
   // HibernateUtil.setup("create table EVENTS ( uid int, name VARCHAR, start_Date date, duration int);");

```
// hibernate code start
    HibernateFactory.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = HibernateFactory.openSession();
    Session session2 = HibernateFactory.openSession();
    Event event = new Event();
    event.setName("Name");
    session.save(event);
    session.flush();
    Event event2 = (Event) session2.load(Event.class, event.getId());
    System.out.println(event2.getName());
    HibernateUtil.checkData("select uid, name from events");        
// hibernate code end
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The code was probably written for HSQLDB 1.8 which had limited transaction capabilities. Current versions expect each connection to run in its own thread within the database. Use two separate threads.

Comment: Ok it appears that the code above will not work. You need to create a transaction so a session.beginTransaction();  and a session.getTransaction().commit();  is needed. Please look for this code if you try an Hibernate example.